# Dynamic Expression to access a Child of a ICollection<Child>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, expression

I'm trying to build out a Dynamic Expression to access the Child of an ICollection with reflection to use as an OrderBy clause.

Ultimately what I would like is an end result of an Expression.Lamba<Func<Parent, object>> that is similar to this:

```
p.Children.Select(c => Property.GetValue(c.ChildB))
```

Haven't really seen a clear way to access ChildB from Parent.ChildrenA. Any suggestions or links to how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that `Property` is a reference to a property (`PropertyInfo`) on the type of the `ChildB` property. The given delegate can be built as shown in the example below. Since the `Select` method will always return an object of type `IEnumerable`, so this is used as the return type for the delegate.

Dynamically building expression trees gets pretty verbose, pretty quickly, as also shown in the example.

Example:

```cs
class Question
{

    public class Parent
    {
        public ICollection<Child> Children { get; } = new HashSet<Child>();
    }

    public class Child
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Child ChildB { get; set; }
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        PropertyInfo childBProperty = typeof(Child).GetProperty(nameof(Child.ChildB));
        PropertyInfo idProperty = typeof(Child).GetProperty(nameof(Child.Id));

        // Build expression for the used lambda in the Select call:
        // (Child c) => c.ChildB.Id
        ParameterExpression childParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Child), "c");
        MemberExpression getChildB = Expression.Property(childParameter, childBProperty);
        MemberExpression getChildBId = Expression.Property(getChildB, idProperty);
        LambdaExpression getChildIdDelegate = Expression.Lambda(getChildBId, childParameter);

        // Get reference to the Select method, it is a generic extension method which exists
        // on System.Linq.Enumerable
        MethodInfo genericSelectMethodDefinition = typeof(Enumerable)
            .GetMethods()
            .Where(method =>
                method.Name == nameof(Enumerable.Select)
                && method.IsGenericMethod
                && method.GetParameters()
                    .Any(parameter => parameter.ParameterType.Name == "Func`2"))
            .Single();

        // Build the generic method specifically for the involved types
        MethodInfo selectMethod = genericSelectMethodDefinition
            .MakeGenericMethod(childParameter.Type, idProperty.PropertyType);

        // Build lambda for selecting the result of the previously created lambda
        // for getting Child.ChildB.Id
        // (Parent p) => Enumerable.Select<Parent, int>(p.Children, (Child c) => c.ChildB.Id)
        // which is equivalent to
        // (Parent p) => p.Children.Select(c => c.ChildB.Id)
        ParameterExpression parentParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Parent), "p");
        MemberExpression childrenProperty =
            Expression.Property(parentParameter, nameof(Parent.Children));
        MethodCallExpression childrenLambdaResult =
            Expression.Call(selectMethod, childrenProperty, getChildIdDelegate);
        Expression<Func<Parent, IEnumerable>> childrenLambdaResultLambda =
            Expression.Lambda<Func<Parent, IEnumerable>>(childrenLambdaResult, parentParameter);
        Func<Parent, IEnumerable> result = childrenLambdaResultLambda.Compile();

        // Example usage
        Parent p = new();
        p.Children.Add(new Child
        {
            ChildB = new Child
            {
                Id = 42
            }
        });
        int[] ids = result.Invoke(p).Cast<int>().ToArray(); // Result: [ 42 ]
    }
}
```